# Upgrading Magento 2.1.3 to 2.1.8

Tags: upgrade, cron, magento-2.1.3, cpanel

I'm currently facing an issue with regards to upgrading Magento from `2.1.3 to 2.1.8.`

Unfortunately, My ISP refuses to run commands on their shared hosting server as this affect other clients as well so I've opted to use the admin interface:

> System > Tools > Web Setup Wizard

And run the setup but getting numerous errors.

Here is readiness check fails errors:

[image: Readiness Check]

I've logged in to my CPanel and set up the cron jobs like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/bin/magento cron:run | awk '{ print strftime("\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S"), $0; fflush(); }' 2>&1 >> ~/magento_cron.log
/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/update/cron.php | awk '{ print strftime("\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S"), $0; fflush(); }' 2>&1 >> ~/magento_cron.log
/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run | awk '{ print strftime("\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S"), $0; fflush(); }' 2>&1 >> ~/magento_cron.log
```

But this has not lead to any success. Upgrading my PHP version is a minor issue but could someone please be so kind as to advice what I could potentially be doing wrong?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can upgrade by CLI.

Comment: Are you trying  upgrade to magento2.18

Comment: If you want to use the Setup Wizard, you have to determine why the cron readiness check is failing, too. Check the cron recommendations in the official docs and compare them to what you have on your server.

But as others have mentioned below, the command line upgrade should be easier.

Comment: I am busy troubleshooting why there are a problem with the cron jobs and I am comparing them to the official documentation. CLI would be much easier but my ISP refuses to run the upgrade command. @MartySMagemojoSupport

Comment: @SureshChikani Unfortunately I don't have any access to SSH or CLI.

Comment: @shivashankarm Yes I am trying to upgrade from 2.1.3 to 2.1.8 as Magento has a bug where the cart is associated with the wrong customer.

Comment: Did you tried the below  answer given by me

Comment: Then find a better host, Magento 2 isn't for bottom barrel shared plans.

Comment: Step by Step Process https://magecomp.com/blog/upgrade-magento-2-x-to-latest-version/

Answer (score 3):

Steps to Upgrade:

```
step1:install the composer:

step2:remove the cache, page_cache and generation from magento var

step3:composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.8
--no-update

step4:composer update
```

Then follow the links:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 2):

You can upgrade from CLL. Run below commands in Root of your magento installation:

```
   composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.8 --no-update
    composer update
    rm -rf var/di var/generation
    php bin/magento cache:flush
    php bin/magento setup:upgrade
    php bin/magento setup:di:compile
    php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

It works smoothly. Detail [Documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/bk-release-notes.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the route I planned on taking, but my ISP won't run any of these commands as they are considered 'unsafe' and they will affect all of the other clients on the shared hosting platform.

Comment: Ok, but CLI is best/easy option because you will have lot of problem in admin interface for simple task. If possible, try to get access OR send Commands to server-support to execute these commands on your root magento installation.

Comment: You are 110% correct. Send through these commands to the server support who came back and said they're unsafe :/ only option will be to move hosting providers.

Answer (score 2):

update using CLI

php bin/magento --version >> to know version

1. php composer.phar require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.8 --no-update

   > > composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.8 --no-update
2. php composer.phar update

   > > composer update
3. Clean cache, and di and generation folders.
4. bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: Thank you for this but unfortunately I can't upgrade using CLI. Will try and get my ISP to only run the upgrade commands as I can clear those folders manually.

Answer (score 0):

It worries me how the hosting has been set up, as it means the websites are not self contained, and one being hacked could lead to the whole server being compromised. If you are running an e-commerce business then I'd suggest moving provider if/when you can.

Comment: Palmer Site is an eComm site but it's on a shared hosting server so it's not self-maintained