# Magento 2 Upgrade Issue using composer

Tags: magento-2.1, composer, magento-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade `Magento 2.1.1` to `Magento 2.1.9` using following command.

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.9 –-no-update
```

Following `composer.json` of root directory.

```
{
"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.1.1",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.1",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "mirasvit/module-search-ultimate": "^1.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
    "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
},
"config": {
    "use-include-path": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": "app/code/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"prefer-stable": true,
"repositories": {
    "0": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    },
    "mirasvit-ssu": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://USERID:XXXX@packages.mirasvit.com/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
}
}
```

I am getting error as follow.

[image]

Any thing wrong while upgrading magento ?

Comment: Did you run   "composer update" after this?

Comment: No i am trying to resolve this error. It will work properly ?

Comment: try command "composer update" and post back the outcome.

Comment: let me try but i will update magento ? did you try ?

Comment: try this. And always have backup of files and database before such updates.

Comment: Its is not update in magento admin panel footer

Comment: Ok. Follow as answer posted. composer require magento/product-community-edition:2.1.9 –-no-update. You missed colon (:) . try that and after that "composer update" . And you can also follow: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/191814/29175

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66385/discussion-between-new-bee-in-magento-and-jai).

Comment: After upgrade css file is not genareting always genrate .less file

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition:2.1.9 –-no-update
```

note the : instead of a space after `product-community-edition`

Comment: it is not working in this cases